# XPATH - Extract content between two positions with different indent (python)

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm trying to get some data from an HTML file via url. Here's an example:

```
<html>
    ...
    <div class="start">

        <!-- Everything from here.. -->
        <p></p>
        <p><a href=''></a>
        <span></span
        <br>
        <!-- ..to here -->

        <div class="end">
            ...
        </div>
        ...
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</html>
```

I'm trying to the the data that is directly under `div class="start"`, but I don't know how, since the div contains almost the whole page. What I do know, is that `div class="end"` comes right after the data I want. Keep in mind that I don't want only the text in between, but the different elements, which in this case i `<p> & <span> & <a>`. Also note that the element types may vary from what is showing in the HTML above.

Google gave me different types of this (without any luck):
`'//*[preceding-sibling::div[@class="start"] and following-sibling::div[@class="end"]]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got close with googling. Looks like what you want is

```
//div[@class="start"]/*[following-sibling::div[@class="end"]]
```

Since `<div class="start">` is the *parent* (not a sibling) of the data you want to select, use `div[@class="start"]/*` in your XPath, instead of `*[preceding-sibling::div[@class="start"]]`.

Comment: @OP: You're welcome. And thanks for correcting "convent" - it was bugging me even though I'd forgotten about it. On the other hand it was kind of amusing. :-)

Comment: Typos tend to happen late at night.. Just searched for convent, and I see why you find it amusing!